# ¿Cómo hacer un checkbox escondido, personalizado?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando hacer un `checkbox` personalizado en el que se cambie el color de fondo de mi `label` según está seleccionado o no, y de esta fora esconder el `checkbox` en si. El código que tengo es este:

```css
.milabel {
  background-color:#c9c9c9;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
input:checked{
  }
```

```html
<input id="micb" type="checkbox"><br><br>
<label class="milabel" for="micb"> Hola mundo! Soy clickeable </label>
```

Sé que con el `input:checked` se puede modificar el `checkbox` en sí para darle cierto estilo pero desconozco.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para cambiar el color del `label`

```css
.checkBoxLabel {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color:#c9c9c9;
  border-radius:5px;  
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkBox:checked + .checkBoxLabel {
  background-color: pink;
  color: #fff;
}

div {
  margin-top: 40px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkBox">
  <label for="check" class="checkBoxLabel">My Label</label>
</div>
```

**Update:**

Para esconder el `checkbox` al seleccionar `label` puedes usar un poco de `jQuery`:

```js
$('.checkBoxLabel').click(function(){
  
  var checkbox = $('#check');
  
  if ( checkbox.css('visibility') == 'hidden' ) {
    
    checkbox.css('visibility','visible');
    
  } else {
    
    checkbox.css('visibility','hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.checkBoxLabel {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color:#c9c9c9;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkBox:checked + .checkBoxLabel {
  background-color: pink;
  color: #fff;
}

div {
  margin-top: 40px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkBox">
  <label for="check" class="checkBoxLabel">My Label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, esto es lo que estaba buscando pero me he dado cuenta de una cosa... el label no es personalizable (no se puede modificar su alto y ancho por ejemplo para tener varios iguales de tamaño sin depender de su contenido) Como se podría hacer algo así?

Comment: @PavloB. Mira, en mi respuesta si que modifico el alto y ancho del label (es donde establezco el color). Un `label` no puede obtener altura y anchura porque es `inline`. Tendrás que ponerlo como `inline-block` o `block` para que pueda obtener altura y anchura. `inline-block` si lo que quieres es poner varios en la misma línea.

Comment: creo que esta mal formulada la pregunta, yo pense que querias cambiar el estilo del checkbox

Comment: @rn3w Yo también, de hecho, me dí cuenta de lo que preguntaba realmente al ver la respuesta de aldanux.

Comment: @PavloB. - Te he dejado un ejemplo como puedes modificar el `<label>`

Comment: @Error404 que hacer en estos casos? modificar la pregunta? o dejarlo asi ya que se entendio viendo algunas respuestas

Comment: @rn3w No sé la verdad, yo de momento he decidido dejar mi respuesta ya que la veo altamente relacionada. Sin embargo, yo simulo el checkbox mientras que el lo que busca es cambiar de color a la label que yo modifico.

Comment: @rn3w De hecho, con el nuevo edit, "checkbox escondido" creo que incluso se ajustaría más a mi respuesta. Creo que sigue sin estar clara la pregunta realmente.

Comment: @PavloB. - Te recomiendo que cambies el titulo que tienes... porque puede confundir esto todo un poco... aunque lo que describes queda bastante claro... Te he dejado ahora otro ejemplo como puedes *esconder* el `checkbox` cuando presionas **solamente** el `label`...

Answer (score 4):

Al checkbox por sí solo no se le puede cambiar el fondo.

Sin embargo, puedes ocultar el `checkbox` y utilizar la `label` que está asociada a el para simular el checkbox. Al estar la `label` asociada al checkbox podremos darle estilos según los eventos que tenga el `checkbox` en cada momento.

En este caso, para el estado del checkbox `false` la label estará en rojo y cuando el estado del checkbox sea `true`, la label estará en verde.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="micb" type="checkbox">
<label class="milabel" for="micb"></label>
<span>Hola mundo! Soy clickable!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

En [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css) tenés esta solución sin labels, spans, etc., solo con `pseudo-elementos`:

```css
    label {
        user-select: none;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        appearance: none;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:after {
        content: '';
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center; 
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        line-height: 14px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 3px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
        content: '✓';
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <label>
        <input id="micb" type="checkbox">
        <span>Hola mundo! Soy clickable!</span>
    </label>
```