# ¿Comó agregar estilo a un checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Necesito agregarle un estilo a mi checkbox para que quede asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch" id="switch">
```

Intente colocar este codigo, pero usa librerias y si la agrego a mi proyecto se daña el css de la pagina:

```html
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form method="post" action="/action_page_post.php">
          <label for="switch">Flip Toggle Switch:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch" id="switch">
            <br>
          <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con que "se daña el css de la pagina" ?

Comment: @lois6b el css se daña, colocare una imagen

Comment: ¿Por qué no miras el código de jQuery Mobile para ver cómo lo hace? Es sencillo de ver sólo tienes que inspeccionar el elemento y darle al botón par ver cómo cambian las clases y qué estilos tiene cada clase

Comment: Mira esta pregunta que también trata sobre personalizar un checkbox, igual te ayuda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41526/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-checkbox-escondido-personalizado/41528#41528

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mira este ejemplo tomado de [Codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/ongtB), usando sólo CSS.

La imagen del background la puedes obviar o cambiarla por otra de tu preferencia.

Codepen es como una librería en línea donde se pueden encontrar interesantes fragmentos de código que nos ayudan a aprender formas de sacarle un óptimo rendimiento al uso de HTML/CSS, combinado o no con Javascript.

```css
/* body background from https://subtlepatterns.com/ */
body { background: #ffffff url(https://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/rough_diagonal.png) top left repeat; } 

.toggleSwitch {
    /* just for presentation */  
    margin:20px 200px;  
}


label {
    /* setup stuff */
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dadada;;
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 1px rgba(00,00,00,.2); */
    
    box-shadow: inset rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2) 0 0px 0px 1px, /* border */ 
    inset rgba(38, 38, 38, .3) 0 -1px 3px 2px, /* soft SD */ 
    inset rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 0 1px 0px 4px, /* top HL */ 
    rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 0 0 3px 2px, /* outer SD */   
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 0 0 3px 2px;
  
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 6%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 7.5%),   -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%, transparent 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 4.5%),   -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1.2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 2.2%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #C7C7C7 0%, #E6E6E6 47%, #C7C7C7 53%, #B3B3B3 100%);
}
label input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0; 
}
label span {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:160px;
  left:-180px;
  top:2px;
  font-size:26px;
  text-align:right;
  color:#444444;
}
label .knob {
    position: absolute;
    margin:0;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index: 5;
    top:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(00,00,00,.75);
    transition: 0.18s all ease-out;
}

label:before, label:after {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  text-shadow: rgba(102, 102, 102, .5) 0 -1px 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 0 1px 0px;
}
label:before {
    content: attr(data-on);
    color:#22baca;
    float:left;
    padding:12px 0 0 8px;
}
label:after {
    content: attr(data-off);
    float:right;
    padding:12px 6px 0 0;
}
label input:checked + .knob {
    left:41px;
}
```

```html
<label data-on="ON" data-off="OFF" class="toggleSwitch">  
  <span>Ninjas</span>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
  <span class="knob"></span>
</label>

<label data-on="ON" data-off="OFF" class="toggleSwitch">  
  <span>Kittens</span>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="knob"></span>
</label>

<label data-on="ON" data-off="OFF" class="toggleSwitch">  
  <span>Zombies</span>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="knob"></span>
</label>

<label data-on="ON" data-off="OFF" class="toggleSwitch">  
  <span>Puppies</span>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
  <span class="knob"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: sabes como puedo cambiarle el fonfo al check?

Comment: Se usa gradientes en el estilo, para personalizar puedes jugar con esta parte: `background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 6%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 7.5%),   -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%, transparent 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) 4.5%),   -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1.2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 2.2%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #C7C7C7 0%, #E6E6E6 47%, #C7C7C7 53%, #B3B3B3 100%);` dando tu estilo personalizado.

Comment: gracias :3 te lo agredezco mucho tu ayuda :#

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```css
 .switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      height: 34px;
    }
    
    .switch input {display:none;}
    
    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    
    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 26px;
      width: 26px;
      left: 4px;
      bottom: 4px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    
    .slider_on {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 8px;
      left: 42px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .slider_on:before {
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    
    .slider_off {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 8px;
      left: 8px;
      font-weight: 700;
      display:none;
    }
    
    .slider_off:before {
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:focus + .slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(46px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(46px);
      transform: translateX(46px);
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider + .slider_on {
      display:none;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider + .slider_on + .slider_off {
      display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="/action_page_post.php">
       <label for="switch">Flip Toggle Switch:</label>
       <br>
       <br>
   <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider_on">ON</div>
    <div class="slider_off">OFF</div>
  </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenos dias amigo,

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera tambien

```
/*! ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap Toggle: bootstrap-toggle.css v2.2.0
 * http://www.bootstraptoggle.com
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2014 Min Hur, The New York Times Company
 * Licensed under MIT
 * ======================================================================== */

.checkbox label .toggle,
.checkbox-inline .toggle {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: 5px
}

.toggle {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none
}

.toggle-group {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: left .35s;
    -webkit-transition: left .35s;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none
}

.toggle.off .toggle-group {
    left: -100%
}

.toggle-on {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0
}

.toggle-off {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0
}

.toggle-handle {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0 1px
}

.toggle.btn {
    min-width: 59px;
    min-height: 34px
}

.toggle-on.btn {
    padding-right: 24px
}

.toggle-off.btn {
    padding-left: 24px
}

.toggle.btn-lg {
    min-width: 79px;
    min-height: 45px
}

.toggle-on.btn-lg {
    padding-right: 31px
}

.toggle-off.btn-lg {
    padding-left: 31px
}

.toggle-handle.btn-lg {
    width: 40px
}

.toggle.btn-sm {
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 30px
}

.toggle-on.btn-sm {
    padding-right: 20px
}

.toggle-off.btn-sm {
    padding-left: 20px
}

.toggle.btn-xs {
    min-width: 35px;
    min-height: 22px
}

.toggle-on.btn-xs {
    padding-right: 12px
}

.toggle-off.btn-xs {
    padding-left: 12px
}
```

veo que usas boostrap, asi que ese te puede servir

Answer (score 0):

Con CSS3 puedes hacerlo....aqui te dejo unos ejemplos:

el html

```
<h1>CSS3 Checkbox Styles</h1>
<em>Click any button below</em>


<div class="ondisplay">

  <section title=".slideOne">
    <!-- .slideOne -->
    <div class="slideOne">  
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideOne" name="check" checked />
      <label for="slideOne"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .slideOne -->
  </section>

  <section title=".slideTwo">
    <!-- .slideTwo -->
    <div class="slideTwo">  
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideTwo" name="check" checked />
      <label for="slideTwo"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .slideTwo -->
  </section>

  <section title=".slideThree">
    <!-- .slideThree -->
    <div class="slideThree">  
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" checked />
      <label for="slideThree"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .slideThree -->
  </section>

  <section title=".roundedOne">
    <!-- .roundedOne -->
    <div class="roundedOne">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedOne" name="check" checked />
      <label for="roundedOne"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .roundedOne -->
  </section>

  <section title=".roundedTwo">
    <!-- .roundedTwo -->
    <div class="roundedTwo">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked />
      <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .roundedTwo -->
  </section>

  <section title=".squaredOne">
    <!-- .squaredOne -->
    <div class="squaredOne">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredOne" name="check" checked />
      <label for="squaredOne"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .squaredOne -->
  </section>

  <section title=".squaredTwo">
    <!-- .squaredTwo -->
    <div class="squaredTwo">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredTwo" name="check" checked />
      <label for="squaredTwo"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .squaredTwo -->
  </section>

  <section title=".squaredThree">
    <!-- .squaredThree -->
    <div class="squaredThree">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" checked />
      <label for="squaredThree"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .squaredThree -->
  </section>

  <section title=".squaredFour">
    <!-- .squaredFour -->
    <div class="squaredFour">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" checked />
      <label for="squaredFour"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end .squaredFour -->
  </section>

</div>
```

el css3

```
@import "compass/css3";

/* $activeColor: #c0392b; //red */
$activeColor: #27ae60; //green
$darkenColor: darken($activeColor, 20%);
/* $background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13460/dark_wall.png'); */
$background: #3498db;

/* .slideOne */
.slideOne {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  label {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label {
      left: 37px;
    }  
  }
}
/* end .slideOne */


/* .slideTwo */
.slideTwo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 14px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 52px;
    background: #111;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 4px;
    background: #fcfff4;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 6px;
      left: 6px;
      background: #333;
      border-radius: 50px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label {
      left: 54px;
      &:after {
        background: $activeColor; /*activeColor*/
      }
    }
  }    
}
/* end .slideTwo */


/* .slideThree */
.slideThree {
  width: 80px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  &:after {
    content: 'OFF';
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  }
  &:before {
    content: 'ON';
    color: $activeColor;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label {
      left: 43px;
    }
  }    
}
/* end .slideThree */


/* .roundedOne */
.roundedOne {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      left: 2px;
      background: $activeColor;
      background: linear-gradient(top, $activeColor 0%, $darkenColor 100%);
      opacity: 0;
      border-radius: 50px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }    
}
/* end .roundedOne */


/* .roundedTwo */
.roundedTwo {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    } 
  }   
}
/* end .roundedTwo */



/* .squaredOne */
.squaredOne {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      left: 2px;
      background: $activeColor;
      background: linear-gradient(top, $activeColor 0%, $darkenColor 100%);
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }   
  } 
}
/* end .squaredOne */


/* .squaredTwo */
.squaredTwo {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }    
  }
}
/* end .squaredTwo */


/* .squaredThree */
.squaredThree {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }    
  }
}
/* end .squaredThree */


/* .squaredFour */
.squaredFour {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #333;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }    
}
/* end .squaredFour */





// ** Page Styling - Nothing to do with the Radio Buttons **
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  background: $background;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  h1, h2, em {
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #000;
  }
  em{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .ondisplay{
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px 0;
    section{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background: #555;
      display:inline-block;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top:5px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow:
        0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
        0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
      &:after{
/*         visibility: hidden; */
        content:attr(title);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 3px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px #000; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

y js

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
//   Hide the border by commenting out the variable below
    var $on = 'section';
    $($on).css({
      'background':'none',
      'border':'none',
      'box-shadow':'none'
    });
});
```