# Marcar un checkbox clickando en su texto asociado

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

Necesito que al dar clic en el texto active el **checkbox** o lo desactive es decir que 
el texto actúe como el mismo **checkbox** 
de qué manera lo puedo hacer este proyecto está en **`Angular 8`** y **`ng prime`**

```
<div class="form-check">
  <p-checkbox   name="defaultCheck1" id="defaultCheck1" class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1" formControlName="PlantaBeneficio" binary="true" (click)="validarAccesos();"> Planta de Beneficio </p-checkbox>
   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
     &nbsp; <b>Planta de Beneficio</b>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto es con angular-material ?

Comment: Si agregas  `<div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="second_checkbox"> <label for="cbox2">Este es mi segundo checkbox</label>
    </div>` y lo pruebas te darás cuenta que los input **`type="checkbox"`** tienen el funcionamiento que buscas

Comment: amigo es con ng prime

Comment: Amigo para lograr esto mismo que me acabas de pasar pero con este control de ng prime

Comment: Revisa esta url (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) tienen el funcionamiento que buscas

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo hacer un checkbox escondido, personalizado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41526/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-checkbox-escondido-personalizado)

Comment: @FranciscoRomero  las preguntas son totalmente diferentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregando los atributos al control de esta forma.

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <p-checkbox name="group1" value="New York" label="New York" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" inputId="ny">
  </p-checkbox>
</div>
```

En `label="` agregas el `label` que necesitas así `label="Planta de Beneficio"`, tu control quedaria asi:

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
     <p-checkbox name="group1" value="Planta de Beneficio" label="Planta de Beneficio" inputId="pb">
   </p-checkbox>
</div>
```